# How to create subheaders in scroll panel on GWT?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder, gwt-rpc

I am trying to create sub headers for the scroll table but not able to specify row span and col span.

I want to create a table like this through the scroll table.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+    
|  Heading1  |           Heading2          |    Heading3        |    
|            |-----------------------------|                    |    
|            |subhead1| subhead2 |subhead3 |                    |    
|            |        |          |         |                    |    
+---------------------------------------------------------------+    
|                                                               |    
|            |        |          |         |                    |    
|            |        |          |         |                    |
|            |        |          |         |                    |  
|            |        |          |         |                    |  
|            |        |          |         |                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Anybody know how to create like this ?

Comment: it can be achieve through `FlexTable`. as it will allow you to do programing like html table.

Comment: Can you pls give me the any example link..bcoz I am totally new to the GWT.I want to create a table like that and add a image in the row of third col and if mouse over to that image, it need to show one popup window.

Answer (score 0):

I think Flex table is what you are looking for. FlexTable's [`FlexCellFormatter`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.FlexCellFormatter.html) has `setColSpan` and `setRowSpan` methods that should allow you to create the headings you desire.

Haven't tested this, but the following code should set the first row as you described:

```java
flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 0, 2);
flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 1, 3);
flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 2, 2);
```

See the [FlexTable](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFlexTable) example for source code.